# Emitting signal not updating the values in GUI

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml

I'm trying to make a very basic timetable app just to learn the basics of Qt. I've researched this quite a bit and cant seem to get an answer to my problem, I emit the signal when I change the value of my subject but the emitting signal does not update the GUI. It definitely is changing the value in the code but the QML GUI does not update it during run time.

I have a class called Day with the following Q_PROPERTY's:

```
    Q_PROPERTY(Period *getPeriod READ getPeriod WRITE setPeriod NOTIFY periodChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString getDay READ getDay WRITE setDay NOTIFY dayChanged)
```

and a member to hold the periods

```
    Period *m_period = new Period[10]; //Of type Period (my other class) which holds my subject string
```

I also have getters and setters for the days and periods(as seen in the Q_PROPERTY) and these two for setting/getting the subject:

```
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getSubject(int t){
    return m_period[t].getSub();
    };
    Q_INVOKABLE void setSubject(int t, QString subj){
    m_period[t].setSub(subj);
    emit periodChanged();
    };
```

With the following signals:

```
    void periodChanged();
    void dayChanged();
```

I also have a class called Period with the following Q_PROPERTY:

```
    Q_PROPERTY(QString getSub READ getSub WRITE setSub NOTIFY subChanged)
```

and a member to hold the subject names:

```
    QString subject;
```

My Period class hold the functions called in day to actually change the QString subject:

```
    QString getSub(){
    return subject;
    };
    void setSub(QString sub){
    subject = sub;
    emit subChanged();
    };
```

With the following signal:

```
    void subChanged();
```

So surely when the subject gets changed using setSubject() in my QML, shouldn't it be emitting the periodChanged() and the subChanged() signals, which should update the GUI? I thought it would but it doesn't seem to be working.

For reference, this is basically how I implemented it in QML:

```
    Label { text: monday.getSubject(2) } //How I display the Subject, the parameter being the period number

    Button{
        text: "Enter"
        onClicked:{
            monday.setSubject(2, "RANDOM_TEXT") //How I set the subject at run time, with the first argument being the period number and second the text I want to change it to
        }
```

Here are the main and class files:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);

qmlRegisterType<Day>("Timetable", 1,0, "Day");
qmlRegisterType<Period>("Timetable", 1,0, "Period");

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

Day monday;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("monday", &monday);

engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
component.create();

return app.exec();
}
```

Day.h

```
class Day : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(Period *getPeriod READ getPeriod WRITE setPeriod NOTIFY periodChanged)


private:
        Period *m_period = new Period[10];

public:
    Day(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Day();

    Period* getPeriod();
    Q_INVOKABLE void setPeriod(Period *p);

    Q_INVOKABLE QString getSubject(int t){
    return m_period[t].getSub();
    };
    Q_INVOKABLE void setSubject(int t, QString subj){
    m_period[t].setSub(subj);
    emit periodChanged();
    };

signals:
    void periodChanged();
};
```

Period.h

```
class Period: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString getSub READ getSub WRITE setSub NOTIFY subChanged)

private:
    QString subject;

public:
    Period(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Period();

    QString getSub(){
    return subject;
    };
    void setSub(QString sub){
    subject = sub;
    emit subChanged();
    };

signals:
    void subChanged();
};
```

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    title: "Timetable App"
    property int margin: 11
    width: mainLayout.implicitWidth + 2 * margin
    height: mainLayout.implicitHeight + 2 * margin
    minimumWidth: 800
    minimumHeight: 600

ColumnLayout {
    id: mainLayout
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: margin

    GroupBox{

        id: timetable
        title: "Timetable"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        GridLayout {
            id: gridLayout
            rows: 11
            flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom
            anchors.fill: parent
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            Label { }
            Label { text: "8:00" }
            Label { text: ...} // Added Labels for times from 8:00 to 17:00

            Label { text: "Monday" }
            Label { text: monday.getSubject(0) }
            Label { text: monday.getSubject(1) }
            Label { text: ...} // Added Labels to display subjects for monday at different times, also did the same for the rest of the week
        }
    }

    RowLayout{
         Button{
            text: "Enter"
            onClicked:{
                monday.setSubject(1, "RANDOM_TEXT") // Set the second period of monday to "RANDOM_TEXT"
                console.log(monday.getSubject(1)) // To check if actually set
            }
         }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you need any more info please just ask

Comment: Having code snippets like that does not help. What is missing is the main (to see how you bridged C++ and QML) and a minimised QML with also that `monday` declaration, which at this point can be a registered time as well as a context property.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo - Thanks for the heads up, I added all of the relevant code, hopefully this clarifies it.

Comment: We the right information the answer came out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are retrieving values via method calls in QML, not via property bindings.

A QML code like this should update

```
text: monday.getPeriod.getSub
```

Obviously calling properties "getSomething" is a bit weird.

Now, your `m_period` suggests that a single `Day` object will have more than one `Period`, which would suggest that you might want a list property instead of a single `Period` object. Something like

```
Q_PROPERTY(QList<Period*> periods READ getPeriods NOTIFY periodsChanged);
```

Using that from QML a bit like this

```
text: monday.periods[0].getSub
```

Or even with e.g. a `Repeater`

```
Label { text: "Monday" }
Repeater {
    model: monday.periods

    Label {
        text: modelData.getSub
    }
}
```

Not related to your update problem but also important to consider:
`NOTIFY` signals trigger binding updates, so you don't want to emit them unnecessarily. I.e. setters that emit those should first check if the new value is actually different than the old value and only emit if they are.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see what you mean about not calling the property bindings, seems to have done the trick!